Reprojection during SLD styling
I wrote a number of SLD styles that make use of wms_bbox to nicely arrange labels based on what portion of certain geometries are visible. After a lot of debugging, I found out that this only works when the output CRS is the same as the underlying data's as data reprojection is done after styling. This means that my styles are trying to intersect a web mercator bounding box with a lat/lon polygon, without conversion, resulting in an empty geometry that discards all my labels.
Is there a way to reproject the WMS bounding box to the data's CRS, or the opposite? Is there a projection setting I'm missing for the SLD functions? I dug through the function list in GetCapabilities and it lists a Reproject function but the style validator says it can't be found.

may be you need to look at a WPS function or a custom function?

WPS is a good lead, I hadn't heard of it and it sounds promising! A custom function does not work, unfortunately. Turns out the geometry objects in the styler have no associated SRID, which is part of why they clearly can't be used together. Without adding an SRID column to the database, it seems there's no way to know what format the geometries are in during styling without modifying GetMap, which I had started experimenting with.

WPS was the solution. A custom reproject function plugin does not work because the geometries in the styler do not have SRIDs assigned, so there is no way to determine the source CRS without additional aid either from the end user or the underlying data source (and is likely why the existing functions don't work properly).
Reading the WPS transformer documentation seems to suggest, to me, that a no-op plugin would result in Geoserver silently transforming the geometries to the requested WMS CRS but I can confirm that is not the case.

The query is then performed against the source datastore, and the transformation process is executed against the resulting dataset. The transformation returns a computed output dataset of the same or different format. If the output has a different coordinate system (CRS) than the requested map it is reprojected automatically.

A WPS plugin that does transform, however, is very straightforward following the tutorials. Here's what I ended up with:
@DescribeProcess(title = "reprojectorWPS", description = "Reprojector WPS Service")
public class ReprojectorWPS implements GeoServerProcess {

    @DescribeResult(name = "result", description = "Your features, reprojected")
    public SimpleFeatureCollection execute(
            @DescribeParameter(name = "data", description = "Features")
            SimpleFeatureCollection obsFeatures,
            @DescribeParameter(name = "wms_crs", description = "CRS to project to")
            CoordinateReferenceSystem wms_crs
            ) throws ProcessException {
        return new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(obsFeatures, wms_crs);
    }
}

SLD snippet:
<FeatureTypeStyle>
<Transformation>
  <ogc:Function name="gs:ReprojectorWPS">
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
      <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
      <ogc:Literal>wms_crs</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>wms_crs</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:Function>
</Transformation>

<Rule>
...
</Rule>

This also appears to have not broken GetFeatureInfo requests, but I can't promise anything.
